# Freeform Pro fieldtype- how to set the return path?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace-freeform-next

In upgrading an ExpressionEngine site from 3.x to 5.2.3, I am switching from using Freeform Classic to Freeform Pro 1.7.12.

In Freeform Classic, there was a Freeform fieldtype where you could set the return path individually per entry (http://docs.solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/classic/getting-started/channel-entry-fieldtype.html). In the new version of Freeform, while that fieldtype exists, I cannot find that same return path functionality (http://docs.solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/v1/overview/channel-fieldtype.html#creating-a-freeform-field).

Does this feature still exist in the new version of Freeform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this currently isn't possible. It's on our list to add support for it in the future however. The only workaround right now would be to have a regular EE Field that contains a list of Form's and ID's/short names and another field for Return URL. You could then pass off the short_name and return URL to the Render tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
   <h3>{title}</h3>
   ...

   {exp:freeform_next:render
      form="{my_ff_formname_field}"
      return="{my_ff_returnurl_field}"
   }

   ...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```